# Looking for the author of a series of books about aliens traveling forward and backwards in time

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration, good-against-evil, julian-may

In this series of books mankind has developed Virtual Copies of scientists to populate Probes sent out exploring space. One probe discovers a planet with an ancient Spire existing on the surface. An alien ship is discovered there. While the human clones are investigating, a different alien ship appears and destroys all traces of the technology. From this point the humans follow the path of these Spires from one planet to another. While being followed by the ships that continue to destroy every location. Eventually the humans learn that the ships destroying the spires are the same entities that built the Spires but are now travelling backwards through time.

I know this isn't a very good description of the series, but its been a while since I read them. I think there was 3 books in all. The series deals with problems humans will face with alien encounters. The alien races they eventually encounter are of various levels of technology and mindsets.

I am also looking for the name of the book or author pertaining to a book about an evil presence that brings about complete darkness on Earth by making the daylight times shorter and shorter each day. Meanwhile large holes appears around the world. Each night various "horrors from hell" exit the holes killing humans each night. Meanwhile, the hero of the story is a person chosen to wield a sword with the ability to give him immortality each time it is drawn. He basically wants to die because he has outlived everyone he has ever cared for. But each time he thinks that he will finally rest in peace he is forced to battle once again and thus restoring his youth again.

I am also interested if Julian May (author of the Pliocene series and the Galactic Milieu series) ever filled in the events that led to the evolution of the Tanu race and Marc Remillard into the Llymic race.

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) I think you have 3 good questions here and would be better served if you broke them out separately.

Comment: To add to Major Stackings, you should edit this question (click the link below the question's body) down to just one, specific question.  Then place your two other questions into separate new questions.

Comment: Answer: this is the Orphans of Earth trilogy by Sean Williams and Shane Dix.  In it, virtual humans sent out in space probes to several different star systems are all contacted by the Spinners, who create fantastic gifts for them and then leave, only to be wiped out by the Starfish aliens days later.  Earth (as a proto-Dyson Sphere) is destroyed by the Starfish after one virtual human-turned-flesh-again returns to Earth via a "hole ship", one of the Spinners' gifts.  Eventually the survivors learn how to flee the Starfish, and that the Spinners are anonymous givers.

Comment: Please do follow the above advice. I haven't read May in a long time and would like to know that answer too!

Answer (score 4):

Julian May, through the Milieu trilogy, did provide some insight about what happened to the Tanu during Marc and Elizabeth's time in the duat galaxy. It was also clear that Marc, because of his immortality gene, had become atoning unifex and led the lylmik to establish the galactic milieu.

About three years ago l posted, on a Facebook Julian May fan page, a very brief outline of how Marc had discovered the Lylmik. This information was provided by Julian herself and I provide it here for all her fans:

> Dear Michael
>
> The living ships of Brede's galaxy were somewhat different. The first one to
>   reach our Milky Way six million years ago was the one that carried the Exiles.
>   Brede's ship was able to enclose a mundane-ish habitat capsule (or create one
>   from its substance) in which the humanoid Exiles traveled. And of course, it
>   had a spouse ...
>
> Now, when Marc and Elizabeth d-jumped to the Duat galaxy to free the
>   Tanu/Firvulag population from torc dependency and introduce other Duat races to
>   Unity, THERE WERE NO LYLMIK. Implicit in my Saga is the notion that Marc and
>   Elizabeth transmogrified into the Mental Man phase of humanity and reproduced,
>   then evolved into Lylmik form rather rapidly. Mental Men don't need human
>   bodies ... or DO they? At an appropriate time--see below for a likely scenario
>   -they migrated back to the Milky Way, led by Marc. He identifies himself
>   somewhere in the Saga as THE Lylmik!
>
> You will recall that it was a psychological thing that made Marc unable to
>   restore his fertility in a regen tank back on earth. He could easily build a
>   tank in the Duat galaxy and engender a race of proto-Lylmik in humanoid form
>   which evolved into "real" Lylmik. Recall how the decadent Lylmik of the Milieu
>   Era took easily to human bodies. Now we know why Marc/Unifex urged this method
>   of revitalization on his Quincunx buddies.
>
> None of the exotic races of the Galactic Milieu knew just how old the Lylmik
>   were. We might assume they were much less than a million years old when Marc
>   and Elizabeth completed the cure for torc-addiction and started many Duat races
>   on the way to Unity.
>
> Thus Marc's redemption was partly accomplished. Perhaps Elizabeth, before she
>   relinquished her life there in Duat, suggested a NEW work for Marc and the
>   Lylmik race back home in the good old Milky Way, where there were countless
>   exotic races with Unity potential, ready to be shepherded by kindly mentors,
>   who would travel chez nous in their spiffy ships.
>
> It would be a long and frustrating task; our galaxy wasn't "ripe" for change
>   like Duat. The Krondaku might have finally come around by 500,000 BC. But
>   imagine how tired of the Milky Way recalcitrants a majority of the Lylmik were
>   by then! On to decadence and elitist withdrawal!
>
> Now you and your Coterie have sampled the unwritten (and never to be written by
>   me) sequel to MAGNIFICAT. As to your original query about Lylmik ships, they
>   were Marc's variation of an ancient Duat race--alas, not requiring shipspouses.
>   To him such a refinement was quite superfluous.
>
> Fond regards,
>
> Julian

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second question - "I am also looking for the name of the book or author pertaining to a book about an evil presence that brings about complete darkness on Earth by making the daylight times shorter and shorter each day. Meanwhile large holes appears around the world. Each night various "horrors from hell" exit the holes killing humans each night. Meanwhile, the hero of the story is a person chosen to wield a sword with the ability to give him immortality each time it is drawn. He basically wants to die because he has outlived everyone he has ever cared for. But each time he thinks that he will finally rest in peace he is forced to battle once again and thus restoring his youth again."

This is Nightworld by F. Paul Wilson. 
Its the sixth and final book in the Adversary Cycle (6 books). The Adversary Cycle is also linked to the Repairman Jack series. The second Adversary Cycle book "The Tomb" precedes the Repairman Jack series (all 15 books) and the final Jack book precedes "Nightworld", the last Adversary Cycle book.

Here's a link to the Authors website where it details the reading order of all the books http://www.repairmanjack.com/forum/content.php?157